# MERN Deployment REST API and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, web-deployment

Do I need 2 seperate domains when deploying a MERN Stack website? 1 for react and 1 for the REST API. I'm learning to use nginx on linux with ec2 in deploying and it will be a first time for me. TIA

Would also like to receive diff. kinds of advice if have one

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. There are multiple approaches on deploying a MERN stack:

1. Have two servers, one serving the frontend, the other one being your NodeJS backend
2. Bundle your frontend and backend using e.g. Webpack and serve your frontend via your backend. That would mean that you only need to deploy a single NodeJS app which handles the frontend as well as the backend.

The number of domains you need is actually another thing. When choosing approach no. 1 you could use your root domain for your frontend server and a subdomain like `api.example.com` for your backend. Choosing no. 2 would only need one single domain because of the single server.

I personally prefer no. 2 for the size of projects I'm doing. There is a really great [repo](https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack) that provides you with the foundation of building a MERN stack app using approach no. 2.

I hope I could help!